# Is there any way to count how many time specific patterns occurred in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, pattern-finding

I have DataFrame which looks like this :

```
    A      B       

0   10    jacket 
1   10    T-shirt
2   20    jacket
3   20    hoodie
4   10    jacket 
5   10    T-shirt
6   20    jacket
7   20    hoodie
.
.
.
```

It is obviously clear that there is a pattern in every **two** rows in this DataFrame, which are :

first_pattern = ('A' = 10 & 'B' =  jacket) with ('A' = 10 & 'B' = T-shirt)

second_patterns = ('A' = 20 & 'B' =  jacket) with ('A' = 20 & 'B' = hoodie)

now I want to count how many times have these patterns occurred.

I expect a result like this :

```
count_first_pattern = 35
count_second_pattern = 82
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Many thanks

Comment: You will need `groupby` and `count`.

Comment: Why isn't the pattern `jacket - T-shirt - jacket - hoodie` with n=2?

Comment: There is nothing obvious about the pattern.